# HTML5 - meta description tag isn't working when shown in google

Tags: html, web, meta

I just put my website onto my godaddy server, with a meta description tag, and I  have also indexed my site with google. When I find the site on a google search, the site description is, "see this godaddy instant page!..." and stuff, Ive tried numerous things, and reuploading, but it doesnt seem to be working... Please help, thanks so much! Heres my head

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Innovative, simplistic, small business web            design/development, Portland Maine." />
    <title>Small Business Web Design/Development.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css"></link>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
</head>**strong text**
```

Comment: have you tried the crawler to reindex your page?

Answer (score 0):

Just wait some hours so that Google can crawl your site again. Did you register your site to [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/%E2%80%8E)?